# Serialize a class into an activerecord field

Tags: ruby, json, activerecord, serialization

I've tried a few different searches, but I'm not really sure how to word the question correctly. Imagine I have a db table create migration that looks like this:

```
def self.up
    create_table :users do |t|
       t.string :name, :null => false,
       t.text :statistics
    end        
end
```

Example users class

```
class User
    serialize :statistics, JSON

    def statistics
        self.statistics
    end

end
```

But I want self.statistics to be an instance of class Statistics

```
class Statistics
    @stats = {}

    def set(statistic, value)
        @stats[statistic] = value
    end

    def to_json(options)
        self.to_json(:only => @stats)
    end
end
```

(or something like that)

Ultimately, what I want to happen is that I want to be able to add Statistics-specific methods to manage the data in that field, but when I save the User object, I want it to convert that instance of the Statistics class into a JSON string, which gets saved in the DB.

I'm coming from a PHP background, where this kind of thing is pretty easy, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to make this work with ActiveRecord (something I don't have much experience with).

Ideas?

*Note: This is NOT Rails... just straight-up Ruby*

Answer (score 0):

Do you need it to be JSON? If not, serializing it to YAML will allow you to easily marshal the object back to its original class.

[ActiveRecord::Base#serialize](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/serialize/class) takes two arguments: `attribute` and `class`. If `class` is defined, the data must deserialize into an object of the type specified. Here's a [cool example of it in action](http://pickardayune.com/blog/2012/08/22/serialized-attributes-in-activerecord-3-dot-2/).

> By default, your attribute will be serialized as YAML. Let’s say you
>   define MyField like this:
>
> class MyField
>
> end
>
> It will be serialized like this:
>
> --- !ruby/object:MyField {}
>
> It will deserialize back to a MyField instance.